# Как найти предыдущий элемент в не блока (jquery)?

Tags: jquery

Возможно вопрос немного странный, но когда покажу пример все станет понятно.

вот такая структура

```
   <div class="mainclass">
      <div class="bigitem">1</div>
      <div class="bigitem">2</div>
      <div class="bigitem">3</div>
      <div class="bigitem">4</div>
      <div class="bigitem">5</div>
    </div>
    <button>new</button>
    <div class="mainclass">
      <div class="bigitem">11</div>
      <div class="bigitem">22</div>
      <div class="bigitem test">33</div>
      <div class="bigitem">44</div>
      <div class="bigitem">55</div>
    </div>
    <button>new</button>
    <div class="last">xxx</div>
```

по нажатию на первую кнопку button нужно что бы после `<div class="bigitem">5</div>` клонировалась такая я же строка `<div class="bigitem">5</div>`

```
   <div class="mainclass">
      <div class="bigitem">1</div>
      <div class="bigitem">2</div>
      <div class="bigitem">3</div>
      <div class="bigitem">4</div>
      <div class="bigitem">5</div>
      <div class="bigitem">5</div>
    </div>
```

по нажатию на вторую кнопку button нужен вот такой результат

```
<div class="mainclass">
  <div class="bigitem">11</div>
  <div class="bigitem">22</div>
  <div class="bigitem test">33</div>
  <div class="bigitem">44</div>
  <div class="bigitem">55</div>
  <div class="bigitem">55</div>
</div>
```

Вот тут https://codepen.io/ctacua/pen/zYpyxaL я пробовал делать это с использованием .clone и .prevAll

```
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button')
    let prev = $('button').prevAll('.bigitem').html()
    console.log(prev)
      
  })
})
```

Буду признателен за совет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял что вам нужно

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    let prev = $(this).prev();
    prev.append(
      prev
        .find('.bigitem:last-child')
        .clone()
    )      
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainclass">
  <div class="bigitem">1</div>
  <div class="bigitem">2</div>
  <div class="bigitem">3</div>
  <div class="bigitem">4</div>
  <div class="bigitem">5</div>
</div>
<button>new</button>
<div class="mainclass">
  <div class="bigitem">11</div>
  <div class="bigitem">22</div>
  <div class="bigitem test">33</div>
  <div class="bigitem">44</div>
  <div class="bigitem">55</div>
</div>
<button>new</button>
<div class="last">xxx</div>
```

Comment: да. спасибо. то что надо. но на реальном примере почему-то не работает 
https://codepen.io/ctacua/pen/zYpyxaL

клонирует не весь элемент (без верхней обертки) <div class="row  mt-3 mb-0 bigitem">

Comment: @Stas у вас в "реальном" примере нет обертки-контейнера для записей как в тестовом `class="mainclass"`. Поэтому в реальном примере запись вставляется внутрь предыдущей.

Comment: @Stas попробуйте сделать таким кодом: `prev.clone().insertAfter(prev)`, чтобы получилось [вот так](https://prnt.sc/kPkLy30gOraj)

Comment: это понятно. но не понятно почему оно берет на уровень ниже. я же пишу .clone именно верхний уровень. по логике, тогда .parent().clone() должно брать на уровень выше, но выходит не так. в первом случае берет на уровень ниже, а с parent берет на уровень выше!

Comment: @Stas если внимательно посмотреть. То ничего не вырезалось. Просто появлялась вложенность

Comment: поздно заметил ваше предыдущее сообщение )))
все заработало, спасибо. а то я что-то затупил!

Comment: @Stas Если все заработало, и в этом помог мой ответ, то пометьте его как верный

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135651/discussion-between-stas-and--).